# linq to sql updates on for loop but not on while loop

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq

I have some linq to sql code. It updates the underlying database if I run it as a for loop, like this:

```
      Dim myDC As MyDataClassDataContext = New MyDataClassDataContext
      Dim processThese As List(Of rec) = (From k In myDC.recs Where k.didSomeStuff = false select k).toList
        For Each o As rec In processThese 
            'do some stuff          
            o.didSomeStuff= True
            myDC.SubmitChanges()

        Next
```

But not if I run it like this

```
    Dim myDC As MyDataClassDataContext = New MyDataClassDataContext
    While (From k In myDC.recs Where k.didSomeStuff  = False Select k).Count > 0
           Dim o as Rec = (From l in myDC.recs where l.didSomeStuff=false select l).first
           'do some stuff
           o.didSomeStuff=true
           mydc.submitchanges()
    end while
```

What might be the reason for this? Is there anything about a while loop that would throw off linq?

Comment: If database is not updated, then you should have either infinite loop or no loops at all. Which is your case?

Comment: @lazyberezovsky infinite loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think problem is different context you are using. In `While` condition you are using `myDC` context. But when you are getting entity to update, you are using `DC` context. You are getting entity from `DC`, changing it, and then you are submitting changes to another context `myDC`. Thus nothing is submitted (there is no changes in `myDC` context) and you have infinite loop.